# Apache Commons Configuration2 how to read data from InputStream

Tags: java, apache-commons, xml-configuration, apache-commons-config

How can I read the data from InputStream by using Apache Commons Configuration2?

```java
FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration> builder = 
    new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration>(XMLConfiguration.class)
        .configure(
            new Parameters()
            .xml()
            .setFileName("")
            .setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine())
        );

XMLConfiguration config = builder.getConfiguration();
config.read(sourceJarFile.getInputStream(sourcePropertiesEntry))
```

Gives the above code, I will get the below exception if the setFileName is given empty string.

```
org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException: Could not locate: org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileLocator@61dc03ce[fileName=tmp.xml,basePath=<null>,sourceURL=,encoding=<null>,fileSystem=<null>,locationStrategy=<null>]
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileLocatorUtils.locateOrThrow(FileLocatorUtils.java:346)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler.load(FileHandler.java:972)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler.load(FileHandler.java:702)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.initFileHandler(FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.java:312)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.initResultInstance(FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.java:291)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.initResultInstance(FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.java:60)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder.createResult(BasicConfigurationBuilder.java:421)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.BasicConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(BasicConfigurationBuilder.java:285)
at com.test.installer.App.getXMLConfigurationProperties(App.java:185)
```

If I give null or just not call setFileName(); I will get the unable to load configuration exception at the read() line.

```
org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException: Unable to load the configuration
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.XMLConfiguration.load(XMLConfiguration.java:986)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration2.XMLConfiguration.read(XMLConfiguration.java:954)
    at com.test.installer.App.updateExistedProperties(App.java:84)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [example in the API documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html#File-based_Configurations):

Set up your file parameters (encoding and such):

```
   FileBasedBuilderParameters fileparams = ...    
   FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration> builder =
                    new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<>(PropertiesConfiguration.class).configure(fileparams);
```

and then:

```
FileBasedConfiguration config = builder.getConfiguration();
FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler(config);
Inputstream istream = ...
fileHandler.load(istream);
```

Note that you cannot use autosave with this. To save you'd probably need to provide an `OutputStream`. Something like:

```
fh.save(ostream)
```

Answer (score 2):

Proper way of loading XML configuration data from Input Stream (in commons-collections 2.x) is as follows:

```
XMLConfiguration cfg = new BasicConfigurationBuilder<>(XMLConfiguration.class).configure(new Parameters().xml()).getConfiguration();
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(cfg);
fh.load(inputStream);
```

After calling `load()` `cfg` will contain loaded configuration.

Also note, that using XMLConfiguration.read() method should not be used, as this method is designed for internal use and probably will be renamed to _read() in future (see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONFIGURATION-641).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`XMLConfiguration.read(InputStream in)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/index.html) , but as far as I know, you need to have a XML file somewhere. The reason is that when you either get the configuration from the builder or call the `read` method above, there are a few checks in the private `load` method (line 963 in the [XMLConfiguration.java in the source files](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/rsync.apache.org//commons/configuration/source/commons-configuration2-2.1-src.tar.gz)).

```
    Parameters params = new Parameters();
    FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<XMLConfiguration> fileBuilder =
            new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<>(XMLConfiguration.class)
            .configure(params.fileBased().setFileName("/tmp/dummy.xml"));`

    XMLConfiguration xmlConfiguration = fileBuilder.getConfiguration();
    xmlConfiguration.read(inputStream);
```

The dummy file can be anything as long as it’s well-formed, it doesn’t need to be valid. In my case, `/tmp/dummy.xml` just contains `<_/>`.